# Retrieving the Selected RadioBox Checked value dynamically passing radioname in JQuery

Tags: jquery

i have group of radio buttons in different name. I have to select those values dynamically.
here is a example code of that.

```
    <input type="radio" id="@(item2.QuestionId):@(item3.OptionId)_mt" columnvalue="@i" value="@(item2.QuestionId):@(item3.OptionId)" name="@(item2.QuestionId)_selectedobjects" />
```

when i click submit button i get those arrays.

```
   var name={748_selectedobjects, 749_selectedobject, 750_selectedobjects}
```

now i need to find out the radio box selected for each name. 
how can i do this in Jquery.

I am trying with

```
       $('input[name=748_selectedobjects]:checked').Val();
```

how can i pass name dynamically ?

Thanks.

Comment: `val()` is lowercase - is that just a typo in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [attributes ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) and then iterate on the returned elements and for example store the columnvalues in an object

```
var checked = {};
$('input[name$=_selectedobjects]:checked').each(function(){
    //With this command you retrive the column value
     checked[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('columnValue');
 });
```

`checked` will be an object whoes properties are the name of the radio buttonsand values the value of the checked radio

EDIT - if you need to find those objects inside a form element you should pass the form element as a context:

```
var form = $('#myform_' + splitstr[0]);
$('input[name$=_selectedobjects]:checked', form)//just select those elements inside your form
```

Comment: i get my form id as this. var form =  ('#myform_' + splitstr[0]);  how could i find those in respected form

Comment: @Chakradhar pass your form as a context in the selctor, i updated my answer to sdhow you how

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Nicola Peluchetti will work fine, but if you wanted to be a little more exact in your code the following will also work:

```
for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
    $(':radio[name=' + name[i] + ']:checked').val();
}
```

The major difference is that the above answer will select ALL inputs (selects, radios, text fields) that match the selector (ending in "_selectedobjects") where as my this will only select a radio with the given name that is selected.